# Is it possible to play the Back to Karkand maps in regular Conquest mode?

Tags: battlefield-3, back-to-karkand

Whenever I try to play Conquest (either via quick match or the server browser) on the Back to Karkand maps, I always end up playing Conquest Assault. Is there a way to play regular Conquest on these maps? If so, is it possible to filter out Conquest Assault when choosing a server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gulf of Oman map has regular Conquest mode. Rest of them have only Conquest Assault.

BTW. for statistics purposes (badges, medals, assignments etc.) Conquest Assault is counted as Conquest.

Comment: ...except for at the end of a Conquest Assault game you will not get a conquest ribbon, at least not with the latest update

Comment: @Earlz: until April update you did get Conquest ribbons.

Comment: @Earlz: indeed seems that with latest update it doesn't give ribbons. I'm guessing it's a bug that they are gonna fix either by giving Conquest ribbons or introducing new Conquest Assault ribbon.